# How do I use functions from a managed DLL in VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, dll, com-interop

I have a simple C# function I wish to use from VBA. For the question's sake, lets say the routine in C# looks like this:

```
using System;
namespace MyTestLibrary
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        static string Shout(string message)
        {
            return message + "!";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use it on the VBA end like so. This causes an error ("Cannot find DLL entry point "Shout"):

```
Public Declare Function Yell Lib "C:\blah\MyTestLibrary.dll" Alias "Shout" (phrase As String) As String

Sub test()
    MsgBox Yell("Hello World")
End Sub
```

Further research showed a workaround as (and I have gotten this implementation to work) :

```
Sub test()
    Dim y As MyTestLibrary.Class1
    Set y = New MyTestLibrary.Class1
    MsgBox y.Shout("Hello World")
End Sub
```

However, this does not meet my requirements as I cannot deploy my library alongside my workbook as I must manually add the reference. Not a big deal for individual use, but a headache when you have to deploy it to non-tech oriented end users, as each dll must be referenced manually.

**TLDR** How do I use a static functions made with C# in VBA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a C# dll inside EXCEL VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340041/using-a-c-sharp-dll-inside-excel-vba)

Comment: Shouldn't you make your class static as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just not possible. You need to create a COM wrapper in C# or VB.Net with an equivalent non-static function and call that instead from your VBA program.

Comment: The [link provided by GSerg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340041/using-a-c-sharp-dll-inside-excel-vba) should get you started with the COM approach.

Comment: Actually, [that guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/35443/robert-giesecke) there offers a template for creating exported functions with C# that are usable with `declare function` from VBA. It's still COM interop, but with a twist and without the burdensome registration.

Comment: @GSerg I did not follow the link at first, now I did, and it is indeed impressive! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Forms Interop` project, and maybe you can figure it out. If you can call a form from VB6/VBA you can call a function.

link: [`http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/VB6_-_C__Interop_Form.aspx`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/VB6_-_C__Interop_Form.aspx)