Multi-tasking in excel VBA
I'm kind of trying to do multi-tasking in VBA. I've a function for say job1, In job1 after doing some task I'm waiting for 5 seconds and then continue and while I wait I want to finish another job, say job2. And if possible I would like to time-out the job2 if doesn't finish in 5 seconds and go back to Job1 to continue.
Is this even possible? Does VBA support any background timer that I use here? Or any kind of utility that can help in getting this task done?
So far I've not found anything directly, and I'm only trying to achieve it with VBA code but struggling.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159025/multithreading-in-vba-excel

"if possible I would like to time-out the job2 if doesn't finish in 5 seconds" whether you could do this would depend on the details of job2.  Maybe you can provide more details around exactly what jobs 1 and 2 involve.
