# DLL created in C# does not show members when referenced in Excel-VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am new to C# and am trying to create DLLs with functions that I can use in VBA.  I have created a test DLL with simple functions that work fine when referenced in another C# assembly.  I am also able to reference the DLL in VBA, and the class created by it (named FunctionsVS) appears in the object browser.

In VBA, I have the following code snippet:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim func As New FunctionsVS
    z = func.Add(4, 5)           
End Sub
```

When I run this sub, I get I get an error message stating

*"Class not registered"*.

I have tried to register the DLL with regsvr32 but I get an error stating:

*The module "c:\windows\system32\functionslibframework.dll" was loaded but the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found.*

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The C# code I used to create the DLL is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionLibVS
{
    public class FunctionsVS
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public int Multiply(int x, int y)
        {
            return x * y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a C# dll inside EXCEL VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340041/using-a-c-sharp-dll-inside-excel-vba)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a C# dll inside EXCEL VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340041/using-a-c-sharp-dll-inside-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Generate the tlb file using regasm.exe
regasm /tlb /codebase functionslibframework.dll

Then reference the *.tlb in VBA in Project -> References

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).